# Group by clause query with derived fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, group-by

My table has quantity, sale price and sale date, and I need to derive the sales price and group the sales by month. I used the below but wasn't able to get the group by clause right.

```
select 
    (QUANTITY*SALEPRICE) as sales,
    DATEPART (month, saledate) as MM
from [dbo].[PETSALE]
GROUP BY DATEPART (month, saledate)
```

Comment: what's the error are you getting?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an aggregate function in the `select` clause to make your statement a valid aggregate query.

I would phrase your query as:

```
select 
    sum(quantity * saleprice) as sales,  -- aggregate function
    year(saledate) yyyy,
    month(saledate) mm
from [dbo].[petsale]
group by year(saledate), month(saledate)
```

Note that I added the sales year to the `select` and `group by` clauses: in case your data spreads over more than 12 months, you probably don't want sales from the same month in different years to be grouped together. But if you do, you can just remove `year(saledate)` from the query.